# Sonataadmin list field inline edit on empty fields

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I am playing around with SonataAdmin. I have a list of users in my backend and i want to make specific fields inline editable within the list.

```
->add('email', 'string', array('editable' => true))
```

Works well until there is an object without a value for email. So i am able to edit the email directly as long as the field email got a value. When it's empty i am not able to edit it from within the list.

Comment: To be complete, this is fixed in `sonata-admin 2.4`, see (your GitHub issue): https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/2902 and https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/2881.